# react native AsyncStorage firebase JSON value '<null>' of type NSNull cannot be converted to NSString

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am using `AsyncStorage` to store some Firebase user data.

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('firebaseUser', JSON.stringify(data))
```

React Native is blowing up with the below error when I try to retrieve the data

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('firebaseUser')
```

> JSON value '' of type NSNull cannot be converted to NSString
>       +[RCTConvert NSString:] + 226 RCTConvert.m:56

It appears that Firebase comes back with some `null` data (`displayName`, `photoUrl`, etc.) Not sure if it's related.

Versions:

```
"react-native": "^0.31.0",
"firebase": "^3.3.0",
```

Update:
I actually narrowed it down to the Firebase module is using `AsyncStorage` to store its own data. When that happens, I get the JSON `<null>` error. When I clear `AsyncStorage`, it works again. Here's what the Firebase data object looks like:

```
"{
  "uid": "XwsK2",
  "displayName": null,
  "photoURL": null,
  "email": "test@test.com",
  "emailVerified": false,
  "isAnonymous": false,
  "providerData": [
    {
      "uid": "test@test.com",
      "displayName": null,
      "photoURL": null,
      "email": "test@test.com",
      "providerId": "password"
    }
  ],
  "apiKey": "xLxzuyPlUqA88kEfy",
  "appName": "[DEFAULT]",
  "authDomain": "abc.firebaseapp.com",
  "stsTokenManager": {
    "apiKey": "xLxzuyPlUqA88kEfy",
    "refreshToken": "AJiUa4Y7b",
    "accessToken": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzjQzYzU3Nzk5NGVmNGNiy_DlQ8xQO7kq3YXxgntE9Q8YJA",
    "expirationTime": 1472098951672
  },
  "redirectEventId": null
}"
```

Comment: AsyncStorage can handle null fields on objects just fine, that's not the issue here. Perhaps paste the stringfied `data` object here for easier debugging?

Comment: @jevakallio, I added some more details. Thank you for chiming in!

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong in the code I see, afraid I can't be of any help. Good luck! :)

Comment: Look like the correct way is:  `JSON.stringify(data || {})`

Comment: I have the same issue, Did you get the asnwer?

Answer (score 5):

AsyncStorage expects you to give it a `string` when calling `setItem`, but you are giving it an object. Try stringifying the firebase data before you save it:

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('firebaseUser', JSON.stringify(data));
```

And parsing it when you read it back:

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('firebaseUser').then(data => data ? JSON.parse(data) : null);
```

Comment: I actually am stringifying it. Otherwise it wouldn't save at all. I modified the question to reflect that.