# "JSON value '<null>' of type NSNull cannot be converted to NSString" in React Native when trying to store object as string in AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I have the same exact issue as here but nobody has seemed to answer it and I can't comment:

[react native AsyncStorage firebase JSON value '<null>' of type NSNull cannot be converted to NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39059800/react-native-asyncstorage-firebase-json-value-null-of-type-nsnull-cannot-be)

Below is my code where it's breaking:

```
loginWithLocal = async () => {
try {
  const result = await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/auth/local/login",
    { email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password})
  const { error } = result.data
  if (error) {
    this.setState({ error })
  } else {
    const { user } = result.data
    console.log("USER", user)
    await this.props.logIn(user);
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user))
    this.props.navigation.navigate("App");
  }
} catch (e) {
  console.log("MY ERROR", e.message, e.response)
}
}
```

I've console logged `user` so I know it's an object but I keep getting this error the `else` block runs.

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log(JSON.stringify(user))`?

Comment: Maybe your user object is returned null.